# Unexpected results in testing a stateful React component with hooks?? (Jest)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to testing, creating simple component with counter state and useState react hook that increment the counter when a button is clicked:

**Component:**

```
const Counter= () => {
    const[counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const handleClick=() => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{counter}</h2>
            <button onClick={handleClick} id="button">increment</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Counter.test.js**:

```
it('increment counter correctly', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<Counter/>);
    const counter  = wrapper.find('h2');
    const button = wrapper.find('button');
    button.simulate('click')
    console.log(counter.text()) // 0
})
```

Logging `counter.text()` after simulating button click print 0 instead of 1;
and when i tried to spy on useState, i got the same problem:

```
it('increment counter correctlry', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<Card />);
    const setState = jest.fn();
    const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');

    useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setState]);
     const button = wrapper.find("button")
     button.simulate('click');
     expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
})
```

This test fails and i get this error after running the test:

```
Expected: 1
Number of calls: 0
```

**What am i doing wrong??**

Comment: I think `console.log(counter.text())` gives the wrong answer because you obtain that reference before updating the counter. Try moving that statement until after the button is clicked.

Comment: Also, your spy breaks the hook because it doesn't actually update the counter value. Your mock `setState` is a no-op. If you're going to mock `useState`, you'll need a persistent reference to an array that you can then mutate inside your test. Otherwise, even if the component is flawless, it will fail the test because it's relying on a broken impl of `useState`.

Comment: @Tom the statement is already after simulating the button click, can you give me some demo code of how to fix mocking useState??

Comment: It turns out that implementing a mock version of React's setState hook is pretty hard. Don't do it. Try doing `wrapper.find('h2')` _after_ you do the click. And you may need to wrap the click inside of RTL's `act`.

Comment: @Tom, some  people advised me to migrate to react-testing library as Enzyme is hard to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `enzyme` v3, you should re-find the `h2` shallow wrapper after you trigger the click handler. Then you will get the new `h2` shallow wrapper reference which contains the latest value of `counter`. Check [migration-from-2-to-3.html#calling-props-after-a-state-change](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.html#calling-props-after-a-state-change) for more info.

E.g.

`Counter.jsx`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Counter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{counter}</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick} id="button">
        increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Counter.text.jsx`:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { Counter } from './Counter';

describe('64148085', () => {
  it('increment counter correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
    const button = wrapper.find('button');
    button.simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('h2').text()).toBe('1');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64148085/Counter.test.tsx
  64148085
    ✓ increment counter correctly (12ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 counter.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.472s, estimated 12s
```